# Glassfish4 server & jersey2: why does glassfish provide its own jersey2 to application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, glassfish, classloader

Recently I tried to deploy a Jersey2 application to Glassfish4.1. I had lots of dependency issues and found a lot of ClassCastException.

Later I found the user guide here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-glassfish

I have to configure pom.xml like:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

> If you are using Glassfish application server, you don't need to package anything with your application, everything is already included. You just need to declare (provided) dependency on JAX-RS API to be able to compile your application.

My question is that why Glassfish have to provide jersey2 (JSR implementation) itself for application. Why not just let application to choose the JSR implementation it is using?

I also add `glassfish-web.xml` under `WEB-INF`:

`<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>`

According to the document here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beagb/index.html):

It will let Glassfish to load classes under `WEB-INF/lib/` first. But why does Glassfish still use its own jersey version and javax version?

For javax, I guess Glassfish is a java application version and it only support specific JSR implementations. So when I choose JSR implementation in my application, and I have to find out the correct version of Glassfish.

But why is jersey2 so special that glassfish have to provide it. What if I want to use another version of jersey2?

---

Updated:

I ran some more tests.

When I deployed a jersey1 application (jersey1 is included in war file) to glassfish4 and asked glassfish4 to delegate class loader process to its parent, and this application works, and application can handle incoming rest requests. Why? I guess since glassfish does not have jersey1 included, it will load jersey1 from libraries inside war file, and glassfish4 is actually working with jersey1. Does this mean I can override glassfish default behavior to let application to choose the JAX-RS implementation.

And if I replaced jersey1 with jersey2 and still let glassfish4 to load libraries from war first, there was an exception thrown:

`WebModule[/invoiceLoader]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider to org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:713)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getRankedComponentProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:743)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$600(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$4.get(ApplicationHandler.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$4.get(ApplicationHandler.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)`

How did this exception happen?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is that why Glassfish have to provide jersey2 (JSR implementation) itself for application. Why not just let application to choose the JSR implementation it is using?

Because Glassfish is a Java EE compliant server, and JAX-RS is part of the EE spec. So it needs an implementation of JAX-RS to run a JAX-RS application. It just happens to use Jersey as the implementation , just like JBoss uses RESTEasy. If the server didn't have an implementation, then it wouldn't be EE compliant. An application should be able to run a complete EE application only compiling the application against the single EE jar. It shouldn't have to know anything about implementations.

> What if I want to use another version of jersey2?

You can just try to replace all the Jersey implementation jars with new ones. See [Updating Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/).

Comment: Thanks!!!! It explains everything!!! So if I want to choose Glassfish to run a JAX-WS application, I have to use Jersey during development? Why not just provide a JAX-WS api for a JavaEE application server? And if I want to deploy a servlet application to Tomcat, and then do I also need to exclude servlet implementation from application war file?

Comment: Because the API have no engine. If the server is to be compliant with the specification, it should provide the engine to run the applications.  What good is being an EE compliant server if I have to provide my own implementation for all the different specs, like EJB, CDI, Servlets, JAX-RS, JAX-WS. If I need to provide my own implementation of these specs, why would I not just use a server like Tomcat. The point of using the EE application servers, is that it provides these implementations out of the box. If you do not want an implementation, replace it, if possible.

Comment: Otherwise use a server that doesn't have any implementation like Tomcat. And yes, if you want to use Tomcat, it is suggested you exclude the servlet-api. as the server already has it.

Comment: I see. During development, it does not matter whether I am using Jersey or RESTEasy, since those implementation are both followed by same api (JAX-WS). When I deploy war file to javeee server, server will find a specific implementation for that.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use anything implementation specific if you want it be portable. You need to just compile against the JAX-RS api jar, instead of using an implementation specific jars.

Comment: @peetskillet is correct, if you want to be portable, you should not use any features of Jersey/RESTEasy except for the JAX-RS API. Therefore it is wise to remove the dependency on `jersey-container-servlet` artefact altogether and leave just `javax.ws.rs-api` (in provided scope).

Comment: I ran some tests today and had some follow-up questions. Could you help me to answer the questions? Sorry I had lots of dumb questions.